# argument-aware alias command?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, zsh

I want to create an alias for `curl` which automatically writes the file it `curl`s into a file with the same name in the current directory.

For example:

```
% curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
    curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py > get-pip.py
```

Is there a way to make the alias read the following argument and insert it into the actual executed script like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases don't handle arguments. Fortunately, functions do:

```
mycurl () {
    curl "$1" > "${1##*/}"
}
```

Where `${1##*/}` is a form of Parameter Expansion which says "Remove everything to the last slash in $1".

Answer (score 2):

If you *needed* to do this, I'd do it with a bash function or (in even more complicated circumstances) in its own script file in `~/bin/`...

But you  could just use `wget` instead of `curl`. It should do what you're asking by default and as an added bonus, you'll get to sidestep the issue that is a URL without a specified file (eg: `http://example.com/`).

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds, where you can use combination of environment variables (`PWD`), command substitutions or IO redirections inside the aliases. Here is some closest example (in Bash):

```
alias curl='xargs -I% curl -o "%" "%" <<<'
```

which will save file with the same name as the URL:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Warning: Failed to create the file https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

This can be further corrected by converting that URL into filename by [manipulating string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) using shell operations, command substitution, `basename`, `awk` or some other tools.

Alternatively you can always point your `curl` to `wget`:

```
$ alias curl=wget
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
'get-pip.py' saved
```